# Regular Expression for matching a phone number

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression to match phone numbers.  I just want to know if the number is probably a phone number and it could be any phone format, US or international.  So I developed a strategy to determine if it matches.

I want it to accept the following characters:  `0-9` as well as `,.()-` and optionally start with a `+` (for international numbers).  The string should not match if it has any other characters.

I tried this:

```
/\+?[0-9\/\.\(\)\-]/
```

But it matches phone numbers that have + in the middle of the number.  And it matches numbers that contain alpha chars (I don't want that).

Lastly, I want to set the minimum length to 9 characters.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for any help, I'm obviously not too swift on RegEx stuff :)

Comment: Unfortunately, only allowing numbers that will be a valid phone number is very troublesome when it comes to international. The length and style of international numbers varies greatly. It is however possible to say you want a 9 digit or greater number like he did below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're pretty close. Try this:

```
^\+?[0-9\/.()-]{9,}$
```

Without the start and end anchors you allow partial matching, so it can match `+123` from the string `:-)+123`.

If you want a minimum of 9 *digits*, rather than any characters (so `---...///` isn't valid), you can use:

```
^\+?[\/.()-]*([0-9][\/.()-]*){9,}$
```

or, using a lookahead - before matching the string for `[0-9/.()-]*` the regex engine is looking for `(\D*\d){9}`, which is a of 9 digits, each digit possibly preceded by other characters (which we will validate later).

```
^\+?(?=(\D*\d){9})[0-9\/.()-]*$
```

Comment: +1 This does answer the criteria stated in the question. The ITU standard that defines telephone numbering is probably worth mention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164

Comment: Note - You may have to escape the slashes using `\/` - I hallucinated the `.net` tag, so I didn't include it. Actually, I'll add it in just to be safe.

Comment: This actually won't work because you didn't escape the () / or . properly. At least it won't work in the languages I have used. Although the syntax is correct.

Comment: @mattimus - What flavor are you testing this on? You usually don't have to escape them in character classes. Here's an example: http://rubular.com/r/TrNUkWUiyT Some languages also need `/` to be escaped, which I've edited into the answer 12 minutes ago `:)`

Comment: I ended up with /^\+?[ \/.,()-]*([0-9][ \/.,()-]*){9,}$/  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it matches alpha character is because of the period. You have to escape it. I don't know what editor you are using for this, this is what I'll use for VIM:

```
^+\?[()\-\.]\?\([0-9][\.()\-]\?\)\{3,\}$
```

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't true. You don't have to escape the dot in a character class (`[.]`). Also, you shouldn't escape `?`,`{` and `}` in your regex, but should escape the `+`.

Comment: You are right about the dot escape, but I do have to escape ?, { and } for VIM. I don't know what you guys are using to write regex, so I'm just giving my knowledge based on VIM.

Comment: Very interesting variation - it seems opposite at first, but it does make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The juqeury has a plugin for US phone validation. Check this [link](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS). You can also see the regular expression in the source code.