# Regular expression for phone numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying:

```
\d{3}|\d{11}|\d{11}-\d{1}
```

to match three-digit numbers, eleven-digit numbers, eleven-digit followed by a hyphen, followed by one digit.
But, it only matches three digit numbers!

I also tried `\d{3}|\d{11}|\d{11}-\d{1}` but doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are many topics on using regular expressions to match phone numbers: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=regex+phone+number

Comment: I've also tried \d{3}|\d{11}(-\d{1})* but doesn't work.

Comment: Phone numbers for what country (or countries) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular Expression for matching a phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395058/regular-expression-for-matching-a-phone-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first part of an alternation matches, then the regex engine doesn't even try the second part.

Presuming you want to match *only* three-digit, 11 digit, or 11 digit hyphen 1 digit numbers, then you can use lookarounds to ensure that the preceding and following characters aren't digits.

```
(?<!\d)(\d{3}|\d{11}|\d{11}-\d{1})(?!\d)
```

Comment: hi Anon. According your saying, i used \d{11}-\d{1}|\d{11}|\d{3} and it worked. tanks.

Comment: Did you mean (?<!\d) and (?!\d) for the anchors?

Answer (score 1):

There are *many* ways of punctuating phone numbers. Why don't you remove everything but the digits and check the length?

Note that there are several ways of indicating "extension":

```
+1 212 555 1212 ext.35
```

Comment: because i just want use regular expression

Comment: Check the length for what, precisely?

Answer (score 0):

\d{7}+\d{4}  will select an eleven digit number.  I could not get \d{11} to actually work.

Comment: In addition to matching an eleven digit number, `\d{7}+\d{4}` will also match 18, 25, 32, 39 etc. digit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work: `/(?:^|(?<=\D))(\d{3}|\d{11}|\d{11}-\d{1})(?:$|(?=\D))/`
or combined `/(?:^|(?<!\d))(\d{3}|\d{11}(?:-\d{1})?)(?:$|(?![\d-]))/`

expanded:

```
/ (?:^ | (?<!\d))       # either start of string or not a digit before us
  (                     # capture grp 1
      \d{3}                 # a 3 digit number
    |                     # or
      \d{11}                # a 11 digit number
      (?:-\d{1})?           # optional '-' pluss 1 digit number
  )                     # end capture grp 1
  (?:$ | (?![\d-]))     # either end of string or not a digit nor '-' after us
/
```