# Home Phone Number Regular Expression

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

Could anyone please give a regular expression for jQuery validation on a home phone number which will force the following criteria:

- 11 Digits exactly
- Must begin with 0
- Must NOT begin with 07

I currently have a regex which forces 11 digits beginning with 07:

```
/^07\d{9}$/
```

This works fine for a mobile number but just need a slightly modified version for a land line.

Comment: This has been covered dozens of times on SO - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395058/regular-expression-for-matching-a-phone-number][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395058/regular-expression-for-matching-a-phone-number

Comment: Why do you want to reject _my_ home phone number?

Comment: What you are doing is almost certainly wrong. Don't do it.

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 Sorry I am new and should have searched past questions before posting. I am sending leads to a company and this is their specification. Sending phone numbers which do not match this criteria will result in an error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either do simple

```
/^0[0-689]\d{9}$/
```

or a look-ahead like

```
/^0(?!7)\d{10}$/
```

Please bear in mind to make it not to restricitive, for example allow spaces (and just remove them before validation) to make the input more user-friendly.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize JavaScript's dialect of regular expressions had look-ahead capability. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
/^0[012345689]\d{9}$/
```

I made a [test harness](http://jsfiddle.net/Yg8Uh/) for it as well.

Comment: +1, although I'm guessing `0` is also not allowed as the second number as this would result in an international call.

Answer (score 1):

I think this regular expression would match what you want.

```
/^0[0123456890]\d{9}$/
```