# regular expression for custom phone number

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)
>   [Regular Expression for matching a phone number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395058/regular-expression-for-matching-a-phone-number)

I need a regular expression to validate phone numbers.
       The conditions are:
            (i) min 7 digits and max 15 digits.
            (ii) Possible valid values are

> 111111  or  111-1111  or  111-1111 ch 111.

Please help me reach a solution.

Comment: what u have tried so far??? have u google it

Comment: ch 111 - it may have string with couple of words and then continue with digits.

Comment: your first *possible value* has 6 digits

Comment: possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/), [Regular Expression for matching a phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4395058/), [Regular Expression for matching a phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3256547). [What is this for](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? A regex may not be the best solution.

Comment: There is also [regular expression library](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?categoryId=7&cattabindex=6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) available. Just copy/paste the right regex.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('/^(\D*\d){7,15}\D*$/', $subject)
```

ensures that `subject` contains 7 to 15 digits, and doesn't care about anything else.

Comment: +1. A little note: the question is about PHP, not Javascript :)

Comment: @J0HN: Thanks - there was a jquery tag when I answered; I completely missed the php tag...

Comment: fine, but if have input like '111--111111', it should not be valid. But the expression returns true..

Comment: @sathish: Then you must specify *exactly* what your allowed input forms are (and do this in your question, not as an answer to this comment). Your comment from above "it may have string with couple of words and the continue with digits" is highly unspecific.

Answer (score 1):

use this code to check is it phone:

```
function isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
var pattern = new RegExp(/^\+?(\d[\d\+\(\) ]{5,}\d$)/);
return pattern.test(phoneNumber);
};
```

on your keyup or blur your input, call this function:

```
function validatePhone() {
var phone = $("input#phone").val();
if (!isValidPhoneNumber(phone)) {
    return false;
} else {
    return phone;
}
};
```

Comment: /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{4})$|^([0-9]{3}[- /]?[0-9]{4} [a-z]{2} [0-9]{3})?$/